# value error of incompatible wrong dimension during training a model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, decision-trees, numpy

I was implementing a **decision tree** on a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/amazon-alexa-reviews). Before that, I wanted to transform a particular column with **CountVectorizer**. For this, I am using **pipeline** to make it simpler.

But there is an *error* of incompatible row dimensions.

### code

```py
# Imported the libraries....
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as cv
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder as ohe
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer as ct
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline as mp
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as dtc

transformer=ct(transformers=[('review_counts',cv(),['verified_reviews']),
                             ('variation_dummies', ohe(),['variation'])
                            ],remainder='passthrough')

pipe= mp(transformer,dtc(random_state=42))

x= data[['rating','variation','verified_reviews']].copy()
y= data.feedback

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test= tts(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42,stratify=y)
print(x_train.shape,y_train.shape)             # ((2205, 3), (2205,))

pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)                       # Error on this line
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-a981c354b190> in <module>()
----> 1 pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    584                                                     exp=brow_lengths[i],
    585                                                     got=A.shape[0]))
--> 586                     raise ValueError(msg)
    587 
    588                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 2205, expected 1.
```

[image: pic]

### Questions

1. How is this **error of incompatible row dimension forming**?
2. How it can be solved?

Comment: Does it  give this error only with the pipeline?

Comment: @BlackCurrant, i did not try indivudually. i tried directly with the pipeline.

Comment: Well, I tried and found so far-  there is an issue in trace showing with  return self._hstack(list(Xs)), because while its going through hstck its reshaping its value incorrect. we can change the data into numpy array and pass it but then in the pipeline some of the transformation isn't accepting numpy values. you may want to run it individually first and check which one is accepting which and  transform the data before passing fit fr the complete pipeline.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795511/unable-to-use-featureunion-in-scikit-learn-due-to-different-dimensions

Comment: @BlackCurrant..thanks for the input. Just clarifying..now i have to do the CountVectorizer and OneHotEncoder indivudually to the respective columns and then apply the decision tree..right ? Any way to use the pipeline l?

Comment: yes. basically debugging where its throwing this error.

Comment: @BlackCurrant, Last Question...Is there any way to use the pipeline combining both transformers?

Comment: Yes. Once you figure out which transformation is causing the problem. Then we can transform pass the data accordingly to pipeline.

Comment: @BlackCurrant..wow..that's great. Suppose CountVectorizer is causing the problem.Then how to deal with that?..Any example or code ?

Comment: well.. if that is the case then we see why its doing so.understand what its expecting and why. then may be  call it before passing the data to pipeline.

Comment: @BlackCurrant..Thanks a lot  for guiding all the time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108079/discussion-between-tedd-and-blackcurrant).

Comment: @BlackCurrant, i have found the answer and it was weird. check now :)

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#make-column-transformer), whenever the transformer expects a 1D array as input, the columns were specified as a string ("xxx"). For the transformers which expects 2D data, we need to specify the column as a list of strings (["xxx"]).

so the code below will work.

```
## Important: i have passed the columns a string to CV and list of columns to OHE

transformer=ct(transformers=[('review_counts',cv(),'verified_reviews'), 
                             ('variation_dummies', ohe(),['variation'])
                            ],remainder='passthrough')
```

Credit goes to Another man who helped me on this.

Comment: That's good. Its actually here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298242/valueerror-input-array-dimensions-not-right-for-countvectorizer

Comment: @BlackCurrant...yes :)

Comment: I opened it to post the solution to get me some votes and found that you got it already. its good to know.in future if you would like to debug it in detail here is something-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911481/keeping-track-of-the-output-columns-in-sklearn-preprocessing

Comment: @BlackCurrant..Thanks for guiding me...i really appreciate it. ps - i have recently started reading ML :)